# How to apply styling to docxtpl

Tags: python, jinja2, docxtpl

I have created a template and I successfully write to variables like this:

```
tpl = DocxTemplate(r"template.docx")

context = ({"issue_date" : "16-Jan 2021", "na_us_guid_new": "1. 13-Jan-2021: abc"})
tpl.render(context)
tpl.save(r"testing.docx")
```

I need to bold and underline this : 13-Jan-2021. But I haven't found any resource. How do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Bold and underline the `{{issue_date}}` expression in your template document:

[image: screenshot from Word]